# Defining custom macros to be used in build events

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, macros

I am trying to define custom macros like pretty commonly done in c++ solutions to be used in, but not limited to, build events in .net core.
For example, I would like to extend pre-defined macros such as `$(SolutionDir)` or `$(ProjectDir)` into `$(MyCustomPath) = $(SolutionDir)\Data`. Then in post build event I would like refer to the newly created `$(MyCustomPath)` such as

```
dotnet abc.dll MyCustomPath
```

I have reached the properties page but I have not seen where I can define new ones
[image]

Comment: What is your end game here? i mean no there is no macros like in C++, only relatively clunk post and pre build events. But what is it you are really wanting to acheive

Comment: Hi there! Just like I mentioned in my question, there are a couple of pre-defined macros, all I want is add my own custom macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never done this before, however you **can** do this

Edit your project file,

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MYMACRO>Whatever you want here</MYMACRO>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then in your build events you can call

```
$(MYMACRO)
```

To prove it works

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked as expected. However, I am very surprised that such a simple function is not documented at all, or at least is hard to come by...